# What does the pattern \d{10} mean?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm validating a form via an XML schema, and I get this error:

```
[facet 'pattern'] The value '12' is not accepted by the pattern '\d{10}'
```

What does `\d{10}` mean? Where can I go to learn more about pattern facets?

Comment: FYI: the pattern here has nothing to do with design patterns. When it says `facet 'pattern'`, all it means is that the error comes from the "[facet](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp)" of the XSD schema that deals with regex patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\d{10}` means you should have 10 characters matching any decimal digit (including [0-9])

Comment: For reference you can have a look at the w3c site (not so easy to follow) or here : http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html

Comment: Technically, I think it also includes other characters in the Unicode [decimal digit class](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)

Comment: This answer is mis-leading, because `\d` includes a *ton* of characters beyond just the numbers 0 to 9.  If you just want those numbers, you should use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: @james and xan: thx, I have updated my answer according to your comments

Comment: How can I write regular expression which only accepts 10 digit number starting either from 6 or 7 or 8 or 9? I want to validate mobile number which start with 6,7,8,9.

Comment: @Talk2Nit maybe it's better to ask another question. But if I understand you correctly, you need something like [6-9][0-9]{9}

Comment: @VincentBiragnet Thanks for the reply. I got the regular expression for this ^([6789]\d{9})